# Как правильно написать предложение

Tags: орфография

1. Цена от производителя на весь ассортимент.
2. Цены от производителя на весь ассортимент.
3. Цены от производителей на весь ассортимент.

Уже второй день ломаем голову. Подскажите как правильно написать это предложение.

Answer (score 1):

(если это для привлечения покупателей)

На весь ассортимент (товаров) - цены производителя(лей).

При цене не должно быть предлога: это просто цена, установленная производителем, его цена - он по ней продаёт. Предлог "от" уместнее при "товаре" (откуда, от кого товар - от его производителя). Единственное или множественное число - менее важно, хотя для розничного покупателя привычно единственное число (ему не так важно знать, один производитель или несколько - он приучен к тому что "цена от производителя" - это хорошо). Для оптовиков же множественное число при "производителе", возможно, несёт дополнительную информацию. А вот "цена" должна быть во множественном числе - **ассортимент** предполагает целый ряд **товаров**, на каждый из которых своя цена (нет понятия "цены ассортимента" - имеются в виду **товары** со своими **ценами**).

Comment: СПАСИБО! очень грамотно звучит ваше предложение! Спасибо!